# Upgrade kaminari to 1.0.1 using rails admin and active_support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, kaminari

I want to update my dependencies, it works if I specify the kaminari version to be `0.17.0`

But now with this version of kaminari i can't make rails_admin work anymore, see here the error I got => https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2939

When I don't specify a version of kaminari i get this error =>

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- kaminari/hooks
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/mongoid-audit-1.0.2/lib/mongoid-audit.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/config/application.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/Rakefile:6:in `require'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/home/mushin-api/mushin-api/source/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.1.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
```

Here is my gemfile.lock

````
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/pyromaniac/active_data.git
  revision: ef3f99524aa2acb7375307aa87c0b129f5e070b4
  specs:
    active_data (1.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      tzinfo

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/Weihrauch/wisper-mongoid.git
  revision: 7db3ea73108fb6d76e4c9e2367e28f5d10e5c17a
  specs:
    wisper-mongoid (0.1.0)
      mongoid (>= 3.1, < 5)
      wisper (~> 1.3)

GIT
  remote: https://github.com/randym/axlsx.git
  revision: 776037c0fc799bb09da8c9ea47980bd3bf296874
  ref: 776037c0fc799bb09da8c9ea47980bd3bf296874
  specs:
    axlsx (2.1.0.pre)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3.4)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.1)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    CFPropertyList (2.3.5)
    actionmailer (4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activejob (= 4.2.10)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    active_model_serializers (0.10.6)
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6)
      activemodel (>= 4.1, < 6)
      case_transform (>= 0.2)
      jsonapi-renderer (>= 0.1.1.beta1, < 0.2)
    activejob (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.10)
      activemodel (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.10)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    api_matchers (0.6.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.5)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.2)
      rspec (>= 3.1)
    api_pagination_headers (2.1.1)
      rails (>= 4.2.0)
    apitome (0.1.0)
      kramdown
      railties
      rspec_api_documentation
    arel (6.0.4)
    ast (2.3.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (7.1.4.1)
      execjs
    avatar_magick (1.0.2)
      dragonfly (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk (2.10.57)
      aws-sdk-resources (= 2.10.57)
    aws-sdk-core (2.10.57)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.0)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-resources (2.10.57)
      aws-sdk-core (= 2.10.57)
    aws-sigv4 (1.0.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    bson (3.2.7)
    bson_ext (1.5.1)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.1.0)
    cancancan (2.0.0)
    case_transform (0.2)
      activesupport
    chewy (0.9.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      elasticsearch (>= 1.0.0)
    climate_control (0.2.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    color (1.8)
    commander (4.4.3)
      highline (~> 1.7.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    connection_pool (2.2.1)
    crass (1.0.2)
    css_parser (1.6.0)
      addressable
    daemons (1.2.4)
    dalli (2.7.6)
    database_cleaner (1.6.1)
    devise (3.5.10)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    docile (1.1.5)
    domain_name (0.5.20170404)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    dotenv (2.2.1)
    dotenv-rails (2.2.1)
      dotenv (= 2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.2)
    dragonfly (1.1.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 1.3)
    easy_diff (1.0.0)
    elasticsearch (5.0.4)
      elasticsearch-api (= 5.0.4)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 5.0.4)
    elasticsearch-api (5.0.4)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-transport (5.0.4)
      faraday
      multi_json
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.5)
    excon (0.59.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    fakeweb (1.3.0)
    faraday (0.13.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    fastimage (2.1.0)
    ffaker (2.7.0)
    fission (0.5.0)
      CFPropertyList (~> 2.2)
    fog (1.42.0)
      fog-aliyun (>= 0.1.0)
      fog-atmos
      fog-aws (>= 0.6.0)
      fog-brightbox (~> 0.4)
      fog-cloudatcost (~> 0.1.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.45)
      fog-digitalocean (>= 0.3.0)
      fog-dnsimple (~> 1.0)
      fog-dynect (~> 0.0.2)
      fog-ecloud (~> 0.1)
      fog-google (<= 0.1.0)
      fog-internet-archive
      fog-joyent
      fog-json
      fog-local
      fog-openstack
      fog-ovirt
      fog-powerdns (>= 0.1.1)
      fog-profitbricks
      fog-rackspace
      fog-radosgw (>= 0.0.2)
      fog-riakcs
      fog-sakuracloud (>= 0.0.4)
      fog-serverlove
      fog-softlayer
      fog-storm_on_demand
      fog-terremark
      fog-vmfusion
      fog-voxel
      fog-vsphere (>= 0.4.0)
      fog-xenserver
      fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.5)
      json (~> 2.0)
    fog-aliyun (0.2.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
      xml-simple (~> 1.1)
    fog-atmos (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-aws (1.4.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.38)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-brightbox (0.13.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.22)
      fog-json
      inflecto (~> 0.0.2)
    fog-cloudatcost (0.1.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.36)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
      ipaddress (~> 0.8)
    fog-core (1.45.0)
      builder
      excon (~> 0.58)
      formatador (~> 0.2)
    fog-digitalocean (0.3.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.42)
      fog-json (>= 1.0)
      fog-xml (>= 0.1)
      ipaddress (>= 0.5)
    fog-dnsimple (1.0.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.38)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
    fog-dynect (0.0.3)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-ecloud (0.3.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-google (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-internet-archive (0.0.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-joyent (0.0.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.42)
      fog-json (>= 1.0)
    fog-json (1.0.2)
      fog-core (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    fog-local (0.4.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
    fog-openstack (0.1.21)
      fog-core (>= 1.40)
      fog-json (>= 1.0)
      ipaddress (>= 0.8)
    fog-ovirt (0.1.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.45)
      fog-json
      fog-xml (~> 0.1.1)
      rbovirt (~> 0.1.4)
    fog-powerdns (0.1.1)
      fog-core (~> 1.27)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
      fog-xml (~> 0.1)
    fog-profitbricks (4.0.0)
      fog-core (~> 1.42)
      fog-json (~> 1.0)
    fog-rackspace (0.1.5)
      fog-core (>= 1.35)
      fog-json (>= 1.0)
      fog-xml (>= 0.1)
      ipaddress (>= 0.8)
    fog-radosgw (0.0.5)
      fog-core (>= 1.21.0)
      fog-json
      fog-xml (>= 0.0.1)
    fog-riakcs (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-json
      fog-xml
    fog-sakuracloud (1.7.5)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-serverlove (0.1.2)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-softlayer (1.1.4)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-storm_on_demand (0.1.1)
      fog-core
      fog-json
    fog-terremark (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vmfusion (0.1.0)
      fission
      fog-core
    fog-voxel (0.1.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-vsphere (1.13.1)
      fog-core
      rbvmomi (~> 1.9)
    fog-xenserver (0.3.0)
      fog-core
      fog-xml
    fog-xml (0.1.3)
      fog-core
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.11, < 2.0.0)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.2)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    gcm (0.1.1)
      httparty
      json
    glebtv_mongoid_userstamp (0.7.2)
      mongoid (>= 4.0.0, < 7.0)
      request_store
    globalid (0.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    google-webfonts-rails (0.0.4)
      activesupport (> 3.2.0, < 5.0)
    grim (1.3.3)
    haml (5.0.3)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    haml-rails (1.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 6.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    highline (1.7.8)
    hike (1.2.3)
    houston (2.2.4)
      commander (~> 4.4)
      json
    html2haml (2.2.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    httparty (0.15.6)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    i18n (0.8.6)
    i18n-js (3.0.1)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.6)
    inflecto (0.0.2)
    intercom (3.5.17)
      json (>= 1.8)
    ipaddress (0.8.3)
    jmespath (1.3.1)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (2.1.0)
    json-schema (2.8.0)
      addressable (>= 2.4)
    jsonapi-renderer (0.1.3)
    kaminari (1.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.0.1)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.0.1)
      kaminari-core (= 1.0.1)
    kaminari-actionview (1.0.1)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.0.1)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.0.1)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.0.1)
    kaminari-core (1.0.1)
    kaminari-mongoid (1.0.1)
      kaminari-core (~> 1.0)
      mongoid
    kgio (2.11.0)
    kramdown (1.15.0)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    letter_opener (1.4.1)
      launchy (~> 2.2)
    libv8 (3.16.14.19)
    logstash-event (1.2.02)
    logstash-logger (0.25.1)
      logstash-event (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.1.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    macaddr (1.7.1)
      systemu (~> 2.6.2)
    mail (2.6.6)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    memcachier (0.0.2)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_magick (4.8.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.10.3)
    mongoid (4.0.2)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      moped (~> 2.0.0)
      origin (~> 2.1)
      tzinfo (>= 0.3.37)
    mongoid-audit (1.0.2)
      activesupport
      glebtv_mongoid_userstamp
      kaminari
      mongoid (~> 4.0.0)
      mongoid-history (~> 0.4.5)
    mongoid-compatibility (0.5.0)
      activesupport
      mongoid (>= 2.0)
    mongoid-history (0.4.7)
      activesupport
      easy_diff
      mongoid (>= 3.0)
    mongoid-paperclip (0.0.11)
      mongoid
      paperclip (>= 2.3.6, != 4.3.0)
    mongoid-scroll (0.3.5)
      i18n
      mongoid (>= 3.0)
      mongoid-compatibility
    mongoid_colored_logger (0.2.4)
      mongoid
    mongoid_orderable (5.1.0)
      mongoid (>= 3.0.0)
      mongoid-compatibility
    mongoid_paranoia (0.2.1)
      mongoid (>= 4)
      mongoid-compatibility
    mongoid_rails_migrations (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.0.0)
      mongoid (>= 4.0.0)
      rails (>= 4.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
    mongoid_userstamp (0.4.0)
      mongoid (>= 3.0.4)
    moped (2.0.7)
      bson (~> 3.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.0)
      optionable (~> 0.2.0)
    multi_json (1.12.2)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mustache (1.0.5)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    open_uri_redirections (0.2.1)
    optionable (0.2.0)
    origin (2.3.1)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (5.1.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0)
    parallel (1.12.0)
    parser (2.4.0.0)
      ast (~> 2.2)
    pdfkit (0.8.2)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    protected_attributes (1.1.4)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.1, < 5.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.0)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.6.8)
    rack-contrib (1.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.4)
    rack-cors (1.0.1)
    rack-pjax (1.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.10)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      actionview (= 4.2.10)
      activejob (= 4.2.10)
      activemodel (= 4.2.10)
      activerecord (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.10)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-api (0.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.11)
      railties (>= 3.2.11)
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.8)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails-i18n (4.0.9)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      railties (~> 4.0)
    rails_admin (1.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (>= 0.7)
      rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
      remotipart (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    railties (4.2.10)
      actionpack (= 4.2.10)
      activesupport (= 4.2.10)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rainbow (2.2.2)
      rake
    raindrops (0.19.0)
    rake (12.1.0)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rbovirt (0.1.4)
      nokogiri
      rest-client (> 1.7.0)
    rbvmomi (1.11.3)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      json (>= 1.8)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      trollop (~> 2.1)
    redis (3.3.5)
    redis-namespace (1.5.3)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    ref (2.0.0)
    remotipart (1.3.1)
    request_store (1.3.2)
    responders (2.4.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
    rest-client (2.0.2)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    roadie (3.2.2)
      css_parser (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
    roadie-rails (1.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.2)
      roadie (~> 3.1)
    rspec (3.1.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-core (3.1.7)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-rails (3.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-sidekiq (3.0.3)
      rspec-core (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.0)
      sidekiq (>= 2.4.0)
    rspec-support (3.1.2)
    rspec_api_documentation (5.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      mustache (~> 1.0, >= 0.99.4)
      rspec (~> 3.0)
    rubocop (0.50.0)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 2.3.3.1, < 3.0)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.9.0)
    ruby_parser (3.10.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.9)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sentry-raven (2.6.3)
      faraday (>= 0.7.6, < 1.0)
    sexp_processor (4.10.0)
    sidekiq (5.0.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      rack-protection (>= 1.5.0)
      redis (>= 3.3.4, < 5)
    simple_enum (2.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    simplecov (0.15.1)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (>= 1.8, < 3)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.2)
    sinatra (1.4.8)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    sprockets (2.12.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    systemu (2.6.5)
    temple (0.8.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.3)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.15)
      ref
    thin (1.7.2)
      daemons (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.4)
      rack (>= 1, < 3)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timecop (0.9.1)
    timeliness (0.3.8)
    trollop (2.1.2)
    tzinfo (1.2.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.4)
    unicode-display_width (1.3.0)
    unicorn (5.3.1)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    uuid (2.3.8)
      macaddr (~> 1.0)
    validates_timeliness (3.0.15)
      timeliness (~> 0.3.7)
    warden (1.2.7)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    wisper (1.6.1)
    wisper-sidekiq (0.0.1)
      sidekiq
      wisper
    wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.3.1)
    write_xlsx (0.85.1)
      rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)
      zip-zip
    xml-simple (1.1.5)
    zip-zip (0.3)
      rubyzip (>= 1.0.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_data!
  active_model_serializers
  api_matchers
  api_pagination_headers
  apitome
  autoprefixer-rails
  avatar_magick
  aws-sdk (< 3.0)
  axlsx!
  bcrypt-ruby
  bson_ext
  byebug
  cancancan
  chewy (~> 0.9.0)
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.1)
  color
  dalli
  database_cleaner
  devise (~> 3.5.4)
  dotenv-rails
  dragonfly
  factory_girl_rails (~> 4.5.0)
  fakeweb
  fastimage
  ffaker
  fog
  gcm
  google-webfonts-rails
  grim (~> 1.3.3)
  haml-rails
  houston
  httparty
  i18n-js
  intercom (~> 3.5.1)
  json-schema
  kaminari (~> 1.0.1)
  kaminari-mongoid
  letter_opener
  libv8
  logstash-logger
  memcachier
  mini_magick
  mongoid (~> 4.0.0)
  mongoid-audit (~> 1.0.0)
  mongoid-history (~> 0.4)
  mongoid-paperclip
  mongoid-scroll
  mongoid_colored_logger
  mongoid_orderable
  mongoid_paranoia
  mongoid_rails_migrations
  mongoid_userstamp (~> 0.4)
  open_uri_redirections
  pdfkit
  protected_attributes
  quiet_assets
  rack-contrib
  rack-cors
  rails (= 4.2.10)
  rails-api
  rails-i18n
  rails_admin
  rake
  rb-fsevent
  redis-namespace
  request_store
  roadie-rails
  rspec-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-sidekiq
  rspec_api_documentation
  rubocop
  rubyzip (>= 1.2.1)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  sentry-raven
  sidekiq
  simple_enum
  simplecov
  sinatra (>= 1.3.0)
  therubyracer
  thin
  timecop
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  unicorn
  uuid
  validates_timeliness (~> 3.0)
  wisper
  wisper-mongoid!
  wisper-sidekiq
  wkhtmltopdf-binary
  write_xlsx

BUNDLED WITH
   1.15.4

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by also upgrading mongoid dependecies.

Apparently, Kaminari 1.0.1 is not compatible with mongoid-audit 1.0.2